# How to set a framelayout to fit the entire screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, android-framelayout

I have a MainLayout, Inside the Mainlayout i have TabWidget and a linear layout view.
At a particular point i want to show a frame layout that will fill the entire screen (hiding the TabWidget and linear layout view)

How to set the size/layout params for the framelayout so that it is displayed filling the entire screen

Answer (score 0):

You should add another layer of FrameLayout on top of your main layout, and add an additional FrameLayout with visibility="gone"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >    
        ...    
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/occasional_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        >    
        ...    
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should make the MainLayout a RelativeLayout in which you put the TabWidget and LinearLayout and last you put a FrameLayout that matches the parent's width and height and that has visibility gone.

Answer (score -2):

You might need to add a FrameLayout outside MainLayout in layout file, then add a LinearLayout/FrameLayout with

android:layout_width="match_parent",android:layout_height="match_parent"

after MainLayout.

Now you can hide MainLayout's content by control visibility of LinearLayout/FrameLayout.